# Cannot find a differ supporting object 'translate(0px, 0px)' in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

In component, I want to translate (drag) the object to some other location and I have this drag method that is being used to translate the object or let say div but I got the error as mentioned in the title.

```
onDragStart(element: HTMLElement) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
    this.translateY = matrix.m42 + 80;
    this.translation = "translate( 0px," + this.translateY + "px)";
    console.log(element);    
}

<div [ngStyle]="translation">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue only by changing

`[ngStyle]="translation"`

to

`[style.transform]="translation"`